# Prevent items to drag below cancelled one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jquery [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/), which is providing drag and drop functionality for items.  
But i want to restrict some items at bottom and don't want to drag and drop it somewhere. So, I searched over API documentation and i found this [solution](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel), which is perfectly fine. but still i'm facing one issue. which is as follows:

[**Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/9KkWn/266/)

```js
$(function() {
        $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
        $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $('.sortable').sortable({ cancel: '.note' });
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="sortable">

            <li id="item_3">Item 3</li>
            <li id="item_4">Item 4</li>
            <li id="item_5">Item 5</li>

            <p class="note">This is a note only</p> 
   </ul>
```

If you run jsfiddle, as per functionality  we cannot drag and drop "this is a note only" line. but we can move other items up and down that fixed line.

So, my question is 
 
**How can I prevent fixed items to stay at bottom. I don't want to allow any items to drag below the fixed one.?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Sortable a 2nd time the way you are is re-initializing it. You need to call Sortable like so:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
  $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
  $('.sortable').sortable("option", "cancel", '.note');
});
```

One problem, the cancel is expecting an element, like `"p"`, not a class.

> Prevents sorting if you start on **elements** matching the selector.

Another problem is that `<p>` should not be a part of a `<ul>` for proper HTML syntax. I would suggest the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    cancel: "p"
  });
  $(".sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

.sortable li,
.sortable p {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}

.sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
</ul>
<div class="sortable">
  <p class="ui-state-default note">This is a Note</p>
</div>
```

This will allow the Note to look like it's part of the list, yet will not be sortable in  any way.

**Update**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    items: "li:not(.note)"
  });
  $(".sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

.sortable li,
.sortable p {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}

.sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default note">This is a Note</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Then set a specific option. See example: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items So basically you'd want to use a `li` with class to identify those items you want to allow sort upon, `items: "li:not(.note)"` would work.